# Calculation of Intersection over union for a mask

Tags: image, computer-vision

I have training labels as images having pixel values 0 or 255. My predicted labels from a machine learning model are also images having pixel values 0 or 255.

255 is the pixel value that prediction is concerned with.

Now I want to calculate IoU.
Here's my approach

```
for k in range(numImages):
    for i in range(width){
      for j in range(height){
        if(label[i][j]==predicted[i][j]){
          if(label[i][j]==255){
            intersection++;
          }
        }
        else if(label[i][j] ==255 || predicted[i][j]==255){
          union++;
        }
      }
    }
    IoU+=intersection/(union-intersection)

IoU/=numImages
```

The final IoU is the value of IoU.
Is this calculation correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic here seems correct although nested for loops/if statements make it somewhat messy. 
A possible alternative might be:

intersection = sum( (A.*B) > 0 );

where A.*B is a pointwise multiplication of the images (i.e. if either image has a 0 at that point, they do not intersect and the product of the respective pixels is 0).

union = sum( (A+B) > 0);

Where A+B is pointwise addition of the images. (i.e. if either is non-zero, then it's part of the union and the sum is greater than 0).

IoU = intersection/union;

I don't know what language you're working in so the syntax may need to be tweaked but this structure takes your code from 3 for loops and 2 conditionals to 1 for loop and no conditionals.

EDIT:

If you are also interested in figuring out how to calculate other common similarity metrics (e.g. [Dice-Sorenson coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient), [precision, recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall)) using a similar approach of pointwise arithmetic between the two images, take a look at the sample code below. The syntax is for MATLAB but it should illustrate the logic. (Note: nnz = number of nonzero elements. Equivalent to 'sum(X >0 )' used above)

```
%Generate complements of each image (0's to 1's, 1's to 0's)
ref_complement=(ref-1).*-1;
seg_complement=(seg-1).*-1;

%True Positives
TP=nnz(ref.*seg); 
%True Negatives
TN=nnz(ref_complement.*seg_complement);
%False Positive
FP=nnz(ref_complement.*seg);
%False Negative
FN=nnz(ref.*seg_complement);   

%%Calculate metrics
metrics.dice                 = 2*TP / (FP + 2*TP + FN);
metrics.recall               = TP / (TP + FN);
metrics.precision            = TP / (TP + FP);
metrics.AreaDifference       = ((TP + FP) - (TP + FN)) * pixelSize^2;
```

Comment: The last step where I average it over the images, is it correct?

Comment: I also want to know how do we calculate precision and recall for the above problem and does IoU give accuracy? because IoU's denominator does not contain True negatives.

Comment: Edited original post to address question re: precision and recall.


As for whether or not averaging over the images is correct, we need to be clear about what 'correct' means. If you mean is it _mathematically correct_, then yes. If you mean _is it the correct thing to do_ then that's a more nuanced question of data interpretation that comes down to the conventions of the field, the nature of the results you're analysing and the intended application of your algorithm. For that reason, I can't help you much there.